# Can a neural network with random connections still work correctly?

Tags: neural-networks

Let's say we have a neural network with n layers where connections do not simply go from layer i to layer i+1, but can go from any layer i to any layer k such that k > i. For example; connections from layer 1 directly to layer 3, or layer 2 directly to layer n, etc...

Given an arbitrary training function and some chosen activation function for each layer, would such a neural network still work correctly?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "random connection"? This terms isn't clear. For better understanding you can draw simple picture with layer connections in network which you want to train.

Comment: What I mean by random connections is as I explained on the post, an edge from a hidden neuron (or input) in layer i can connect with any neuron in layer k, for k > i

Comment: In what you are describing there is no notion of layer.  You can think of a such a network but I do not know how to train it.  Look at the details of backpropogation algorithm.  It backpropogates error layer by layer.  Having a layered neural net is a simplification to facilitate training.

Comment: Trying it on MATLAB it still treats them layer-wise, and it practically allows connections across any layer. I understand what you mean as this not the standard structure of a neural network, however it somehow still works on MATLAB and was wondering whether anyone has some insight on such a structure.

Comment: So you want build not fully connected neural network? For example you have 3-1 NN structure and you have connection $n_{11}$-$n_{21}$, $n_{13}$-$n_{21}$, but without $n_{12}$-$n_{21}$? (where $n_{ij}$ is any neuron, i - is layer number and j - neuron number in layer)

Comment: In a sense, yes! In fact that is what I have but with the extension also allowing connections like $n_{11} - n_{31}$ , $n_{21} - n_{41}$ , etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup your weight connections which you want remove as $0$. For example you have 3-1 NN structure. Your weights for example:

$w_{11} = 1$
$w_{21} = 0$
$w_{31} = 1$

$w = [w_{11}, w_{21}, w_{31}]$

Input unit for example is:

$x = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]$

First of all you try populate your data in network and check output result. (For easier computation we just get linear layer activator, but it still works for any other). So your output will be:

$output = linear(x w^{T}) = 0.5 * 1 + 0.5 * 0 + 0.5 * 1 = 1$

As you see, zero weight synapse just ignore contribution of input and in output neuron we calculate this connection as zero, so this is the same as we don't have this connection.

**UPDATE:**

So this is also works for weight update, but different algorithms can works in different way in weight updates. After one iteration you can update your zero weight and it will be non-zero. So in this case you can control your training for zero weights and update only non-zero.

Comment: Just to settle this for good, I tested such networks on MATLAB and in some cases I've in fact observed better performances in random networks than actual standard ones. Very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively describing DenseNet-like architectures. The relevant paper is this one: [Densely Connected Convolutional Networks - Huang, et. al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06993).

The basic idea is to connect layer $i$ to all layers $k$ with $k>i$, by concatenating all incoming connections to layer $k$. While the complexity of the network grows quadratically with size, the paper demonstrates that the resulting architectures tend to be much more efficient than vanilla neural networks, requiring less overall neurons, and making considerable savings in terms of model size. In the above paper, comparable accuracy results on ImageNet are achieved with 10x less weights, compared to competing architectures like ResNet.

This is because features from previous layers can now be recycled and reused in lower layers. Note that the above paper ends up using blocks of 4 layers, which are densely connected, so the resulting network isn't exactly fully dense.